# When and where can we order/buy region-free DVD/Blu-Ray of Digimon Adventure tri.?

Tags: merchandise, digimon-tri

According to Wikipedia:

> The first film, Saikai (再会 Reunion?), was released on November 21, 2015 and will be released on region-free DVD and Blu-ray in Japan on **December 18, 2015**.

When can we buy this movie, and where can we order the movie franchise online? Since this will be released in Japan, is there a company that sells and provides international shipping?

Comment: Retagged with [digimon-tri], but I don't know jack about Digimon, so somebody who does should come here and change it back to [digimon] if Digimon Tri isn't different enough to warrant a separate tag.

Comment: I've been told that amazon.jp will ship to the us

Comment: @senshin Digimon Tri is a movie of the digimon anime Franchise. thanks for retagging and editing my question :)

Comment: Amazon Japan does ship to the US (about $10-12 shipping for a single BD, with 2-3 day turnaround, in my experience). For one-off purchases, Amazon Japan is a fine option; for larger purchases, proxying through a service like [Tenso](http://tenso.com/) is likely to be cheaper, albeit slower.

Comment: @ton.yeung hope they release it soon.

Comment: @senshin how about other countries like in asia? would you kindly post your comment as an answer and provide some references so that I can Accept your answer :)

Comment: @senshin uhmmm as of now ,are these titles already available in amazon.jp?

Comment: @MikeAgustin See answer - movies 1 and 2 are currently available for preorder.

Comment: @senshin didn't notice it the first time. thanks for editing your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Amazon Japan](http://www.amazon.co.jp/) ships to the US, and I assume to most other places where Amazon does business. Even if you don't know Japanese, it's fairly easy to purchase stuff from Amazon Japan - when you go to the website, you should see a link that says "in English".

[image]

Click on it, and most (though I don't think all) of the interface gets changed over to English. Product descriptions and stuff don't, though.

Once you've done that, you'll need to make an account, even if you have an account on Amazon US or Amazon UK or whatever. The process is the same as making an account on any other Amazon site.

The product you want to purchase is either [this one for BD](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC-tri-%E7%AC%AC1%E7%AB%A0%E3%80%8C%E5%86%8D%E4%BC%9A%E3%80%8D-Blu-ray-%E8%8A%B1%E6%B1%9F%E5%A4%8F%E6%A8%B9/dp/B012QLKQ3G/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1449718398&sr=8-1&keywords=%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%20tri), or [this one for DVD](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%80%90Amazon-co-jp%E9%99%90%E5%AE%9A%E3%80%91%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC-tri-%E7%AC%AC2%E7%AB%A0%E3%80%8C%E6%B1%BA%E6%84%8F%E3%80%8D-%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E6%8F%8F%E3%81%8D%E4%B8%8B%E3%82%8D%E3%81%97B2%E5%B8%83%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D-Blu-ray/dp/B01822BD3U/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1449718398&sr=8-3&keywords=%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%20tri). In either case, you can pre-order it. If you do place a pre-order, the product should leave Amazon's Japanese warehouse on release day and get to you probably less than a week later.

As far as I know, there is only one option available for global shipping from Amazon Japan. You will be charged probably $10-12 for shipment to the US. I don't know about other countries. If you are in the US, you should choose to pay in USD, so as to avoid foreign transaction fees on your credit card.

Incidentally, you can also preorder the second movie ([BD](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC-tri-%E7%AC%AC2%E7%AB%A0%E3%80%8C%E6%B1%BA%E6%84%8F%E3%80%8D-Blu-ray-%E8%8A%B1%E6%B1%9F%E5%A4%8F%E6%A8%B9/dp/B01822B5HY/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1449718901&sr=8-9&keywords=%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%20tri), [DVD](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%99%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E3%83%BC-tri-%E7%AC%AC2%E7%AB%A0%E3%80%8C%E6%B1%BA%E6%84%8F%E3%80%8D-DVD-%E8%8A%B1%E6%B1%9F%E5%A4%8F%E6%A8%B9/dp/B01822B5CY/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1449718901&sr=8-12&keywords=%E3%83%87%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%20tri)) for when it releases on 2 Apr 2016.

---

Much of the advice above is generally applicable to purchasing any BDs and DVDs from Amazon Japan. Amazon Japan isn't always the cheapest option, but it is definitely the most convenient, at least for US-based buyers. However, if you are planning on purchasing a large number of items in a short period of time, you may be able to save on shipping by using a proxy service like [Tenso](http://www.tenso.com/en). (I assume there are other such services, but I haven't really looked.)

Comment: note: If your using chrome, just press right click and "translate to english" to translate the page from japanase to english.